# Devise + Omniauth Facebook redirecting to signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have followed this guide spot on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

First round it authenticated me, signed me in, and saved me to db.

I cleared browser history and tested a different user.

It takes new user to facebook page to sign in, and after sign in automatically redirects them to

```
 http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up#_=_
```

and does not sign them in or save to DB.  Any Ideas?

Routes

```
 get "static/home"
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
 resources :users

 root 'static#home'
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
        :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        #user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
end


def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
        if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
            user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
        end
    end
end



 protected 
    def password_required? 
    true 
 end 




end
```

devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "#######", "################"
```

omniauth_callbacks

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

home.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is redirecting him.  Turns out it is only his facebook account.  Need to know why his account is doing that...

```
 if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
 else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
 end
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but the wrong is a key-secret used :/

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up#_=_
```

I had exactly the same response. I was running the server locally and looking at the logs, it said it couldn't authenticate the client.

Turns out, it was because I had set the ENV keys locally using `export FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET='xxxxxxx'` which only works if you then run the server from the same tab in your terminal.

Things to try:

1. If using `exports` to set the env key - run `$bin/rails s` from the same tab. Can check if the key has been set by typing in `$printenv` in the terminal.
2. Set env key to the bash profile. [Clear instructions from osx daily here](http://osxdaily.com/2015/07/28/set-enviornment-variables-mac-os-x/).
3. Use [dotenv module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to manage keys.

All the best.